# Why was question about GDAL Python bindings closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

I posted [Adding GDAL as dependency to Python package?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188639/adding-gdal-as-dependency-to-python-package) on the usage of the `pygdal` Python package and it was closed as off topic.

Why are the GDAL Python bindings off topic?

Note that there are over 5,000 questions on [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) and some 2,000 on [gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdal).

Is there any criteria to pre-assess what is off-topic in this domain?

Answer (score 3):

I was not one of the close voters. If I had been, I would be happy to explain why.  To me it seems to meet the criteria to be open which come from the help/on-topic page qualified by Meta Q&As here.

None of the close voters on your question has provided an answer here to explain their votes (and no one is required to explain their vote).

Consequently, we may never know why your question was voted to be closed.

In the meantime, it looks like it was re-opened by someone other than the close voters.